# Where is the error for stringTokenizer used to read and integer number and a string?

Tags: java, parseint, stringtokenizer

I have to read a file in input (.txt file) with Java program and I'm using Eclipse. In the first line, I have a number and a string (ex. "1 studente"). I tried with **stringTokenizer** but I'm getting **NumberFormatException** error on input "1 studente". How can I fix it?

I tried to put an Exception, but then StringTokenizer don't read "studente" and I find another error: **NosuchElementException**.

**Below is the code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("partecipanti.txt"));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line!=null) {
            StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            int cod = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());
            String tipo = tok.nextToken();
            String nome = br.readLine();
            String cognome = br.readLine();
```

...

This the error I'm getting.
**java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 studente"**

Comment: It’s weird. I cannot reproduce. Possibly the char between `1` and `studente` is not a normal space character, but some other char looking like a space, they exist.

Comment: Can you please share you file?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), `StringTokenizer` use is discouraged:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.

You should use `String.split` instead. You can pass a regular expression (`\\s`) to split by whitespace.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("partecipanti.txt"));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line!=null) {
           String[] tok = line.split("\\s");
           int cod = Integer.parseInt(tok[0]);
           String tipo = tok[1];
           String nome = br.readLine();
           String cognome = br.readLine();
        }
}
```